# Replace a string in multiple files with words from a list

Tags: linux, string, sed

I have multiple folders (rep0 to rep6) and inside each of them, there is a file named "file.mdp".
Inside "file.mdp" I would like to replace the string "315" with a different one as follow:

The string "315" will be replaced with different values from this list: 300.00,332.18,366.98,404.54,445.26,489.27,536.92 such that:

```
in rep0, file.mdp, 315 will be replaced with 300.00
in rep1, file.mdp, 315 will be replaced with 332.18
in rep2, file.mdp, 315 will be replaced with 366.98
...
and so on!
```

I tried it with sed this way but it only replaced the file in rep0:

```
sed -i 's/315/300.00/g;s/315/332.18/g;s/315/366.98/g;s/315/404.54/g;s/315/445.26/g;s/315/489.27/g;s/315/536.92/g;/^\s*$/d' rep1/nvt.mdp rep2/nvt.mdp rep3/nvt.mdp rep4/nvt.mdp rep5/nvt.mdp rep6/nvt.mdp rep7/nvt.mdp
```

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
val=(300.00 332.18 366.98 404.54 445.26 489.27 536.92)
for i in ${!val[@]}; do
        sed -i "s/315/${val[$i]}/" rep${i}/file.mdp
done
```

We populate an array with the replacement values.

We iterate over the index (0-6), and use sed to replace the value in each file.

Comment: Thanks $tink. I have two questions please: What if I would like to iterate over a different index (1-7) or anything else, how can I play with this? The second question is: in some lines of file.mdp I have different "315" like this: 315  315  315 on the same line. This script is only changing the first occurrence of 315 on a line but not all of them on the same line. I don't see how I can adapt your script in order to obtain this :/

Comment: @FZJ To address #1:  do bash arithmetic.  I utilised the fact that bash starts counting at 0. If your directories start with one, add 1 to the index.  #2" change the sed to `sed -i "s/315/${val[$i]}/g"` ... that will tackle any occurence of 315 on a line.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and parallel):

```
parallel sed -i 's/315/{2}/g' {1}/file.mdp ::: rep{0..6} :::+ 300.00 332.18 366.98 404.54 445.26 489.27 536.92
```

Link the value to be substituted with its directory and using sed action each file within that directory.